Table of verbs with identical forms despite differing stems
Some verbs have forms that are identical to those of other verbs. That is, these forms are identical despite originating from different stems, due to deletion of the end of their stems.
A simple example would be: both あう (会う; to meet) and ある (to be there, to exist) have the て-form あって.
I'm looking for a resource with comprehensive or "complete" lists of sets of verbs for which certain grammatical forms are identical. Can anyone help?

If you know any programming language, then you could parse JMdict dictionary (which is in XML format) and create such table yourself.
